# Rtl direction in TinyMce scrambles codesample

Tags: django, tinymce, tinymce-plugins, django-tinymce, tinymce-5

my Django-TinyMce direction has turned rtl due to my language and everything looks fine except the code sample plugin which has gotten rtl and scrambles the code. I would appreciate anyone help me figure this out. I want code sample to be ltr while everything else is rtl. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Please follow these steps:

1. Add `directionality` to the list of plugins.
2. Add `ltr rtl` to your toolbar.
3. Before inserting the code sample, make sure the text direction is set to `ltr`.

That's it.

You may read more about this plugin [here](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/plugins/opensource/directionality/).